# GitHub workflow to publish docker container to GitHub Container Registry

Tags: docker, github-actions, publish, docker-registry

Would anyone give me a latest GitHub workflow example to publish docker container to GitHub Container Registry please?

I've

- checked a [blog post written in 2020](https://github.blog/2020-09-01-introducing-github-container-registry/), and
- the official [Publishing and installing a package with GitHub Actions](https://docs.github.com/en/packages/managing-github-packages-using-github-actions-workflows/publishing-and-installing-a-package-with-github-actions)
- Tried to create a workflow using the official `docker-publish.yml` template,

But they all seems to be rather old:

```yaml
      - name: Log in to the Container registry
        uses: docker/login-action@f054a8b539a109f9f41c372932f1ae047eff08c9
        with:
          registry: ${{ env.REGISTRY }}
          username: ${{ github.actor }}
          password: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}

      - name: Extract metadata (tags, labels) for Docker
        id: meta
        uses: docker/metadata-action@98669ae865ea3cffbcbaa878cf57c20bbf1c6c38
        with:
          images: ${{ env.REGISTRY }}/${{ env.IMAGE_NAME }}

      - name: Build and push Docker image
        uses: docker/build-push-action@ad44023a93711e3deb337508980b4b5e9bcdc5dc
```

Not only they are using versions from 3 years ago, the official `docker-publish.yml` template even include a workaround for an old build-push-action issue that has been fixed.

So, would anyone give me a latest GitHub workflow example to build then publish docker container to GitHub Container Registry please? Specially

- my dockerfile is in a subfolder, not at the root of my project
- and I want to add my own tag to the build

yet I haven't found any options for doing then with `docker/build-push-action`. Please help.